# Algebra - rings $2\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Can anyone tell what's the difference between these two rings: $2\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z_3$ ?

I think that ring $2\mathbb Z$ represents remainders when dividing with two, can anyone help? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you mean $2\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z_3$? Or $\Bbb Z^3$? Or $3\Bbb Z$? Or something else?

Comment: @Haus ...... and it is not any of those Arthur listed? Surely you could say which ones were the relevant ones, if so.  The way to type those, respectively is `$2\mathbb Z$` `$\mathbb Z_3$` `$\mathbb Z^3$` and `$3\mathbb Z$`

Comment: $2\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z_3$.

Comment: @Haus Whenever you are asked for clarification, you can respond in the comments, but then you should *also fix your question*. Use the edit button.

Comment: Thank you. I am still learning how to write tasks here.

Comment: $\Bbb Z_{\Large 2}\,$ is the ring of residues (remainders) $\bmod 2.\,$ It is also denoted by $\,\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z,\,\ \Bbb Z/2,\,\ \Bbb Z\bmod 2\ \ $  Furthermore, $\, 2\Bbb Z\,$ is the set (= ideal) of all integer multiples of $\,2\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2\Bbb Z $ is the set of all multiples of  $2$ whereas  $\Bbb{Z}_3$ is the set of all equivalence classes under the relation $\text{R}$ on $\Bbb Z $ such that $a\text{R}b $ if and only if $3|(b-a) $.

**Edit**: $\mathbb Z_3$ is also the standard notation for [$3$-adic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) integers.

Courtesy :@rschwieb

Comment: Some people are going to complain that $\mathbb Z_3$ is also standard notation for $3$-adic integers, so you should probably also add that.

Comment: @rschwieb I'm completely ignorant of the meaning/definition of  $3$-adic integers.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number  Well, if you feel like improving your answer and hedging against that, there you go.  I'm not really sure you'd need to do anything more than mention it, if you wanted.

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you for your suggestion. I've edited my answer.